# Количество цифр в целой части

Tags: c++, constexpr

Как во время компиляции узнать количество цифр в целой части числа?

```
constexpr int a = 5; // ответ 1
constexpr short b = 100; // ответ 3
constexpr double c = 10.5 // ответ 2
```

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ну `compile time` имею в виду, чтобы в `constexpr` выражениях использовать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тем же способом, что и обычно.

Домашнее задание: Придумать, что делать, если дробное число не влезаeт в `long long`.

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int count_digits(long long x) 
{
    int ret = 0;
    do
        ret++;
    while (x /= 10);
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int a = 5;
    constexpr short b = 100;
    constexpr double c = 10.5;

    constexpr int d = count_digits(a);
    constexpr int e = count_digits(b);
    constexpr int f = count_digits(c);

    std::cout << d << '\n';
    std::cout << e << '\n';
    std::cout << f << '\n';
}
```

Comment: точно, а я о шаблонной магии думал, но с новыми стандартами всё проще)